# Extending unification, SICStus-style

Tags: prolog, unification, sicstus-prolog

I want to understand SICStus-style extensible unification.
The [User's Manual on `library(atts)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002datts.html) states that:

> #### `Module:verify_attributes(-Var, +Value, -Goals)`   hook
>
> ...
>
> `verify_attributes/3` may invoke arbitrary Prolog goals, but `Var` should not be bound by it. Binding `Var` will result in undefined behavior.
>
> ...
>
> In the case when a single unification binds **multiple** attributed variables, first all such bindings are **undone**, then the following actions are carried out for each relevant variable:
>
> 1. For each relevant module `M`, `M:verify_attributes/3` is called, collecting a list of returned `Goals`.
> 2. The variable binding is redone.
> 3. Any `Goals` are called.
> 4. Any goals blocked on the variable, that has now become unblocked, are called.

So far, I came up with the following interpretation of the above:

- Different `verify_attribute/3` handlers hooked on `Var`, see the same state of `Var`: All see it "pre_unify".
- `verify_attribute/3` must not bind `Var`, but it may bind *other* attributed variables.
- **These** bindings are to be delayed, too, so that the handlers not only see the same state of `Var`, but of **all** attributed variables involved.

  Above list of actions entails "5. Force any delayed bindings of attributed variables."

Am I moving in the right direction—is **this** what "*done, then undone, then redone*" is all about?
 *Please help!*

Comment: I don't have SICStus Prolog, would a meta-interpreter qualifies as an answer (the interface is almost equivalent to `atts`, only `get_atts/2` and `put_atts/2`, may be wrong)? Are you implementing an engine?

Comment: @notoria. With the SICStus interface, solvers are invoked **pre**-unify, that is before any bindings have been performed; Of course a meta-interpreter would be ok, but I guess it's hard to get the *exact* semantics right.

Comment: @notoria. I am implementing a Prolog system with SICStus style extensible unification.

Comment: @notoria. FYI you can get a free one-month test license at https://sicstus.sics.se/eval.html .

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying the [beta](https://sicstus.sics.se/download_beta.html).

Comment: @notoria. Ok, but how? "There are currently no beta releases, see the main Download Page for downloads." :)

Comment: There was one but now it's gone (and I didn't record the page with important information so it can't break before it expires).

Comment: @notoria. No need to get a beta version. Why not a free one-month trial of the latest official release?

Comment: Can I renew free trial as many as I want?

Comment: @notoria. No, that will not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That mechanism was originally designed by Christian Holzbaur and implemented by yours truly. Re. your interpretation:

> Different `verify_attribute/3` handlers hooked on `Var`, see the same
> state of Var: All see it "pre_unify".

Right.

> `verify_attribute/3` must not bind `Var`, but it may bind other
> attributed variables.

Right.

> These bindings are to be delayed, too, so that the handlers not only
> see the same state of `Var`, but of all attributed variables involved.

Wrong. If it binds other attributed variables, the whole extended unification mechanism gets invoked recursively on those variables.

> Above list of actions entails "5. Force any delayed bindings of
> attributed variables."

Wrong.

Comment: Nice to see you answering.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The way I see it now the "undo then redo" part is not necessary in my implementation (which only deals with finite trees). Does that sound plausible to you?

Answer (score 1):

This is the meta-interpreter:

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [append/2,append/3,maplist/2,maplist/3,member/2,select/3]).

% Source: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_17.html
% Source: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002datts.html#lib_002datts

element(Es, E) :-
    member(E, Es).

get_atts(S, _, _, _, _, _) :-
    var(S),
    throw(error(instantiation_error,get_atts/3)).
get_atts(_, V, _, _, _, _) :-
    nonvar(V),
    throw(error(uninstantiation_error,get_atts/3)).
get_atts(+, V, D, G_3, As0, As) :-
    element(As0, s(V0,D0,G0_3)),
    V == V0,
    \+ \+ s(V,D,G_3) = s(V0,D0,G0_3), !,
    mi([s(V0,D0,G0_3) = s(V,D,G_3)], As0, As).
get_atts(-, V, D, G_3, As0, _) :-
    element(As0, s(V0,D0,G0_3)),
    V == V0,
    \+ \+ s(V,D,G_3) = s(V0,D0,G0_3),
    mi([s(V0,D0,G0_3) = s(V,D,G_3)], As0, _), !,
    false.
get_atts(-, _, _, _, As, As).

put_atts(S, _, _, _, _, _) :-
    var(S),
    throw(error(instantiation_error,put_atts/3)).
put_atts(_, V, _, _, _, _) :-
    nonvar(V),
    throw(error(uninstantiation_error,put_atts/3)).
put_atts(_, _, D, _, _, _) :-
    var(D),
    throw(error(instantiation_error,put_atts/3)).
put_atts(+, V, D, G_3, As0, [s(V,D,G_3)|As]) :-
    functor(D, A, N),
    functor(D0, A, N),
    select(s(V0,D0,_), As0, As),
    V == V0, !.
put_atts(+, V, D, G_3, As, [s(V,D,G_3)|As]).
put_atts(-, V, D, G_3, As0, As) :-
    select(s(V0,D0,G0_3), As0, As1),
    V == V0,
    \+ \+ s(V,D,G_3) = s(V0,D0,G0_3),
    mi([s(V0,D0,G0_3) = s(V,D,G_3)], As1, As), !.
put_atts(-, _, _, _, As, As).




mi(G, As) :-
    mi([G], [], As).

mi([], As, As).
mi([G|_], _, _) :-
    var(G),
    throw(error(instantiation_error,mi/3)).
mi([G|_], As, _) :-
    false,
    writeq([G,As]), nl,
    false.
mi([false|_], _, _) :-
    !,
    false.
mi([true|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    mi(Gs, As0, As).
mi([G0|Gs], As0, As) :-
    functor(G0, call, N),
    N @> 0,
    G0 =.. [call,F|Bs0], !,
    F =.. Bs1,
    append(Bs1, Bs0, Bs),
    G =.. Bs,
    mi([G|Gs], As0, As).
mi([(G0, G)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    mi([G0,G|Gs], As0, As).
mi([(G ; _)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    G \= (_->_),
    mi([G|Gs], As0, As).
mi([(G0 -> G ; _)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    mi([G0], As0, As1), !,
    mi([G|Gs], As1, As).
mi([(_ ; G)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    mi([G|Gs], As0, As).
mi([(G0 -> G)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    mi([G0], As0, As1), !,
    mi([G|Gs], As1, As).
mi([catch(G0, E, G)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    catch(mi([G0|Gs], As0, As), E, mi([G|Gs], As0, As)).
mi([throw(E)|_], _, _) :-
    throw(E).
mi([A \= B|_], As, _) :-
    mi([A = B], As, _), !,
    false.
mi([_ \= _|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    mi(Gs, As0, As).
mi([get_atts(Mode, V, D, G_3)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    get_atts(Mode, V, D, G_3, As0, As1),
    mi(Gs, As1, As).
mi([put_atts(Mode, V, D, G_3)|Gs], As0, As) :-
    !,
    put_atts(Mode, V, D, G_3, As0, As1),
    mi(Gs, As1, As).
% mi([G0|_], _, _) :-
%     functor(G0, A, N),
%     \+ pi(A, N), !,
%     throw(error(existence_error(procedure,A/N),mi/3)).
mi([G0|Gs0], As0, As) :-
    copy_term(G0, G),
    head_body(G, Gs, Gs0),
    unify(G0, G, As0, As1),
    mi(Gs, As1, As).

unify(G0, G, As0, As) :-
    maplist(arg(1), As0, Vs0),
    sort(Vs0, Vs),
    unify_(G0, G, Vs, As0, As).

unify_(G, G, Vs, As0, As) :-
    maplist(var, Vs),
    term_variables(Vs, Vs), !,
    As0 = As.
unify_(G0, G, Vs, As0, As) :-
    unifiable(G0, G, Eqs0),
    shrink_equations(Vs, Eqs0, Eqs),
    gather_attributes_goals(Eqs, As0, As1, Gs),
    G0 = G, % maplist(call, Eqs),
    filter_attributes(As1, As2),
    mi(Gs, As2, As).

shrink_equations(_, [], []).
shrink_equations(Vs, [Eq|Eqs0], Eqs) :-
    call(Eq),
    maplist(var, Vs),
    term_variables(Vs, Vs), !,
    shrink_equations(Vs, Eqs0, Eqs).
shrink_equations(Vs, [Eq|Eqs0], [Eq|Eqs]) :-
    shrink_equations(Vs, Eqs0, Eqs).

unifiable(X, Y, Eqs) :-
    \+ \+ X = Y,
    unifiable_([X], [Y], Eqs, Eqs, []).

unifiable_([], [], _, Eqs, Eqs).
unifiable_([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Eqs0, Eqs1, Eqs) :-
    nonvar(X),
    nonvar(Y), !,
    functor(X, A, N),
    functor(Y, A, N),
    X =.. [A|Xs0],
    Y =.. [A|Ys0],
    unifiable_(Xs0, Ys0, Eqs0, Eqs1, Eqs2),
    unifiable_(Xs, Ys, Eqs0, Eqs2, Eqs).
unifiable_([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Eqs0, Eqs1, Eqs) :-
    element([X=Y,Y=X], Eq),
    \+ maplist(\==(Eq), Eqs0), !,
    unifiable_(Xs, Ys, Eqs0, Eqs1, Eqs).
unifiable_([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], Eqs0, [X=Y|Eqs1], Eqs) :-
    unifiable_(Xs, Ys, Eqs0, Eqs1, Eqs).

gather_attributes_goals(Eqs, As0, As, Gs) :-
    gather_attributes_goals_(Eqs, As0, As, Gss, []),
    append(Gss, Gs).

gather_attributes_goals_([], As, As, Gss, Gss).
gather_attributes_goals_([X=Y|Eqs], As0, As, Gss0, Gss) :-
    % TODO: Investigate `==(X)` and `==(Y)`, since goals are executed.
    filter(ar(1, ==(X)), As0, SubAs0),
    maplist(arg(3), SubAs0, Gs0),
    execute_attributes(Gs0, X, Y, As0, As1, Gss0, Gss1),

    filter(ar(1, ==(Y)), As1, SubAs1),
    maplist(arg(3), SubAs1, Gs1),
    execute_attributes(Gs1, Y, X, As1, As2, Gss1, Gss2),

    gather_attributes_goals_(Eqs, As2, As, Gss2, Gss).

execute_attributes([], _, _, As, As, Gss, Gss).
execute_attributes([G_3|Gs], X, Y, As0, As, [Gs0|Gss0], Gss) :-
    mi([call(G_3, X, Y, Gs0)], As0, As1),
    execute_attributes(Gs, X, Y, As1, As, Gss0, Gss).

filter_attributes([], []).
filter_attributes([s(V,_,_)|As0], As) :-
    nonvar(V), !,
    filter_attributes(As0, As).
filter_attributes([s(V,D,_)|As0], As) :-
    var(V),
    functor(D, A, N),
    functor(D0, A, N),
    element(As0, s(V0,D0,_)),
    V == V0, !,
    filter_attributes(As0, As).
filter_attributes([A|As0], [A|As]) :-
    filter_attributes(As0, As).

ar(N, G_1, A0) :-
    arg(N, A0, A),
    call(G_1, A).

filter(_, [], []).
filter(G_1, [L|Ls0], Ms) :-
    call(G_1, L), !,
    Ms = [L|Ls],
    filter(G_1, Ls0, Ls).
filter(G_1, [_|Ls0], Ls) :-
    filter(G_1, Ls0, Ls).


head_body(true, Rs, Rs).
head_body(A=A, Rs, Rs).
head_body(element([A|_], A), Rs, Rs).
head_body(element([_|As], A), [element(As, A)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(select(A0, [A0|As], As), Rs, Rs).
head_body(select(A0, [A|As0], [A|As]), [select(A0, As0, As)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(maplist(_, []), Rs, Rs).
head_body(maplist(G_1, [A|As]), [call(G_1, A), maplist(G_1, As)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(p(_), Rs, Rs).
head_body(p(a), Rs, Rs).

head_body(var(T), Rs, Rs) :-
    var(T).
head_body(nonvar(T), Rs, Rs) :-
    nonvar(T).
head_body(T0==T, Rs, Rs) :-
    T0 == T.
head_body(T0\==T, Rs, Rs) :-
    T0 \== T.
head_body(sort(As0,As), Rs, Rs) :-
    sort(As0, As).

head_body(freeze(V, G_0), [(
    (   var(V) ->
        put_atts(+, W, frozen(G_0), freezer),
        W = V
    ;   nonvar(V), call(G_0)
    )
)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(freezer(V, W, Gs), [(
    get_atts(+, V, frozen(G0), _),
    (   var(W) ->
        (   get_atts(+, W, frozen(G1), _) ->
            put_atts(+, V, frozen((G0, G1)), freezer)
        ;   true
        ),
        Gs = []
    ;   Gs = [G0]
    )
)|Rs], Rs).

head_body(domain(V, Dom0), [(
    (   var(Dom0) ->
        get_atts(+, V, dom(Dom0), _)
    ;   maplist(nonvar, Dom0),
        sort(Dom0, Dom),
        Dom = [E|Es],
        (   Es = [] ->
            V = E
        ;   put_atts(+, W, dom(Dom), contraction),
            V = W
        )
    )
)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(contraction(V, W, Gs), [(
    get_atts(+, V, dom(Dom0), _),
    (   var(W) ->
        (   get_atts(+, W, dom(Dom1), _) ->
            intersection(Dom0, Dom1, Dom),
            Dom = [E|Es],
            (   Es = [] ->
                Gs = [W=E]
            ;   put_atts(+, V, dom(Dom), contraction),
                % put_atts(+, W, dom(Dom), contraction),
                Gs = []
            )
        ;   Gs = []
        )
    ;   (   element(Dom0, W) ->
            true
        ;   false
        ),
        Gs = []
    )
)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(intersection(Us, Vs, Ws), [(
    (   (Us = [] ; Vs = []) ->
        Ws = []
    ;   [U|Us0] = Us,
        (   select(V, Vs, Vs0), U == V ->
            [U|Ws0] = Ws
        ;   Vs0 = Vs,
            Ws0 = Ws
        ),
        intersection(Us0, Vs0, Ws0)
    )
)|Rs], Rs).

/*
head_body(dif(X, Y), [(
    X \== Y,
    (   X \= Y ->
        true
    ;   put
    )
)|Rs], Rs).
head_body(differentiator(V, W, Gs), [(
    get_atts(+, V, dif(Vs), _),
    (   var(W) ->
        (   get_atts(+, W, dif(Ws), _) ->
            intersection(Vs, Ws, Xs),
            maplist(differentiate(V, W), Xs, Gs)
        ;   Gs = []
        )
    ;   Gs = []
    )
)|Rs], Rs).
% */

test :-
    writeq(freeze), nl,
    mi(freeze(A,false), As),
    writeq([A,As]), nl,
    false.
test :-
    writeq(freeze), nl,
    mi((freeze(A,false),freeze(A,true)), As),
    writeq([A,As]), nl,
    false.
test :-
    writeq(domain), nl,
    mi((domain(X,[5,6,7,1]),domain(Y,[3,4,5,6]),domain(Z,[1,6,7,8])), As),
    writeq([X,Y,Z,As]), nl,
    false.
test :-
    writeq(domain), nl,
    mi((domain(X,[5,6,7,1]),domain(Y,[3,4,5,6]),domain(Z,[1,6,7,8]),X=Y), As),
    writeq([X,Y,Z,As]), nl,
    false.
test :-
    writeq(domain), nl,
    mi((domain(X,[5,6,7,1]),domain(Y,[3,4,5,6]),domain(Z,[1,6,7,8]),X=Y,Y=Z), As),
    writeq([X,Y,Z,As]), nl,
    false.
test :-
    halt.
```

For a quick test run `test/0`.

The predicates of interest are `get_atts/6` and `put_atts/6`. This meta-interpreter doesn't handle module so the interface has been generalized (thus creating new unknown issue).

This hasn't been tested extensively, the predicate `gather_attributes_goals/4` may need a deeper inspection. Only `freeze/2` and `domain/2` has been implemented (but need more testing). Implementing `dif/2` could help in testing it. Implementing cut could also help load a library like `clpz` for testing.

Unification is done with `unify/4` where handling the attributed variables begins.

This is the first implementation polished, it's more something to learn how does it work, I still need to work on something better.

Comment: Question? Any issue?

Comment: `freezer` is a bit broken: `( get_atts(+, W, frozen(G1), _) -> put_atts(+, V, frozen((G0, G1)), freezer) ; true )` should better be `( get_atts(+,W,frozen(G1),_) -> put_atts(+,W,frozen((G0,G1)),freezer) ; put_atts(+,W,frozen(G0),freezer) )` (if you are using the same argument order as SICStus' `verify_attributes/3`).

Comment: But `V` and `W` will unify later.

Comment: Yes, but that unification is *asymmetric*: the attvar `V` will cease to exist. If `W` is an attvar, `V` is demoted to a plain var (pointing to `W`). Thus, all relevant attributes need to be copied from `V` to `W`.

Comment: In this implementation `freezer` doesn't demote variable and which variables remain is decided in `filter_attributes/2`.

Comment: How does `freezer` know which way to copy atts when unifying two vars?

Comment: It doesn't know, in `gather_attributes_goals_/5` `X=Y` and `Y=X`  trigger the goals but it seems that without demotion it would be wrong (try `?- freeze(A, false), freeze(A, true)` and print before `filter_attributes/2`).

Comment: First things first. I value your effort and interesting work. But I already *have* an implementation of said extended unification mechanism and so I set the bounty to reward an existing answer.

Comment: It's OK, I don't have one yet, I get to think about.

Comment: I think that's a good way to get to know the quirks of the interface. The devil's in the details. Anyway, solvers using this interface will run (at least) on SICStus Prolog, Scryer Prolog, and MI-Prolog.